# Auto Populate date in Column when X column is edited MultiSheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am relatively new to this, I work for a small business and I'm trying to make a sort of registry to follow Orders and Cheques and auto dating is a huge time saver.

At the moment I have a working code for the first sheet (see below) it auto dates in the first column upon editing the 2nd column and it works wonders. The issue I am getting is it works on every sheet the same, I would need the 2nd and 3rd sheet to Auto Date when the 3rd column is edited instead of the 2nd.

Can I adapt this script so it works differently on a different sheet on the same doc?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------
 //Auto-Populate date in Column A of when column B is updated 
 //Edited 01/13/16 - MK
 //------------------------------------------------------------

function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 2) { // 2 == column B

    // getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
    var columnXRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 1, eventRange.getNumRows(), 1);

    var values = columnXRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (!values[i][0]) {  // If cell isn't empty
       values[i][0] = new Date();
      }
    }
    columnXRange.setValues(values);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If still need help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `i would need the 2nd and 3rd sheet to Auto Date when the 3rd column is edited instead of the 2nd.` and your title of `Auto Populate date in Colum when X colum is edited MultiSheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUGGESTION

To my understanding, you want your script to dynamically adjust per sheet on where you perform an edit:

- On your first sheet, once a user edits column 2 or `B` a timestamp will be added on the adjacent row on Column 1 or `A`.
- On your second & third sheet, once a user edits Column 3 or `C` a timestamp will be added on the adjacent row on Column 1 or `A`.

You may try this implementation below, with fewer lines of code & you will no longer need to edit your script to define each column but only the sheets themselves in case you'll add multiple sheets in the future:

### Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, e.range.getColumn()).getValue().includes("*") && e.range.getRow() != 1 ? //Checks if the cell being edited under a column title contains an identifier, which is an asterisk sign (*)
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1).setValue(new Date()) : //If true, then the adjacent row on Column A will add a timestamp
    null; //If false, nothing will happen
}
```

### Demonstration

1. Add an ***identifier*** to a **column title** on each of your sheets where you would like the script to only take effect.

> *This sample, an identifier used is an asterisk sign (*) after a **column title** on row 1. But you can use any special character you want by editing the script on the `.includes()` line*
> [image]

2. Once you have saved the sample script on your spreadsheet file, here's the behavior:

> *When you edit any row under a **column title** that contains an ***identifier***, a timestamp gets added adjacent to the edited row on Column `A` as seen here. Otherwise, nothing will be added on `A` column*
> [image]

3. This script will also dynamically work on all sheets under your spreadsheet file depending on where you put the ***identifier***, as seen here:

> [image]

### References

- [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
- [Google Sheets event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [JavaScript String includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)
- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: @marc-andre pouliot I hope this answer helps you. Please feel free to comment if there's any missing Or if I have misunderstood something.

Comment: this looks wonderful and would be great if i add more to that doc i love it,
but
i am gettin an error maybe theres an error in the formating ?

10:14:56 Erreur 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: @marc-andrepouliot It seems you are manually clicking the **Run** button from the Apps Script editor as [seen here](https://imgur.com/a/pJokRI0) instead of just saving it by clicking the **Save project** icon from the editor, go back to your spreadsheet, then reload the page & try it as seen on the **Demonstration** above to trigger the `onEdit()` function.

Comment: @marc-andrepouliot If we answered your question, you may want to click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. That way, they'll be easily recommended to your post on their searches without the need of posting a duplicate question.

Comment: @marc-andrepouliot Just let me know if you still encounter any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const sA = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];
  const cA = [2, 3, 3];
  const idx = sA.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == cA[idx]) { 
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```